# Informix database to MySQL database backup/record replacement with specific tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cron, informix

I am trying to backup certain tables in an Informix database to a MySQL database.

There is an enormous number of records (500,000 +), with a "record" being defined as a set of objects with attributes in a table or tables, e.g. John Smith, DOB 1/1/1999, 123 Cherry Lane, etc.

An example of the data organization would be: (PEOPLE (table) -> Last_Name (Object)-> Smith (attribute). Luckily there is a built-in cron-job table that adds new records and/or updates old records and adds them to the database, but it does not get rid of the old record (for which all of the information could be in different tables):

- A person's identifying info might be in the PEOPLE table, but their purchasing info might be in a separate table named BUY_SELL.

The updated records would have the same ID number, but I need to automatically replace those records with the new ones, and I can't go through each one individually, but each new "record" would have new information in each object and subsequently each attribute.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You may export your data from Informix into flat CSV/TSV files (one table - one file), load them by MySQL into temporary tables then add loaded data into the tables storing data references/integrity and updating it if needed.

Comment: This sounds like a reason for using automatically generated identifiers (usually numbers) to identify 'objects' coherently.  In Informix, that is usually a SERIAL (or BIGSERIAL) column in one table — the primary table that defines which objects exist — and a INTEGER (or BIGINT) column in tables that have a foreign key reference to the (primary key of the) primary table.  Different object types have different primary tables (people may be separate from companies, and are different from stock items or insurance policies or bank accounts or whatever else your organization deals with).

Comment: Generated identifiers are particularly valuable for objects with 'fuzzy' real-world identities.  For example, there could be multiple people called 'John Smith'; each different one can have a different identifier.  This is why social security numbers were invented; it is why account numbers were invented; driver license numbers; credit card numbers; passport numbers; …